# Remove the output of a custom command \fundinginfo{} in a custom class

Tags: macros

For academic purpose, I am using the `whiley-article` document class that I found in [overleaf].

My problem is that I want to remove the "funding information" output, which is generated by the `\fundinginfo{}` command. I tried to comment it, but it does not work. I also tried to comment its definition on the `whiley-article.cls`, but it does not work either.

Here is the `wiley-article.cls` file

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% wiley-article.cls, v1.1, 2017/05/26
% Developed by Overleaf.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{wiley-article}[2017/05/26, v1.1]

%% Definitions for adding journal elements
\def\@jlogo{}
\def\@jname{}
\def\@jyear{}
\def\@jpages{}
\def\@jvolume{}
\def\@jwebsite{}

\def\@runningauthor{}
\def\@corraddress{}
\def\@corremail{}
\def\@fundinginfo{}
\def\@presentaddress{}

\def\@papertype{original article}
\def\@paperfield{}
\def\@paperdoi{}
\def\@paperreceived{}
\def\@paperrevised{}
\def\@paperaccepted{}
\def\@papereditor{}

\newif\if@numrefs
\newif\if@alpharefs
\newif\if@amsrefs
\newif\if@blindreview

%% Add options for other journals here
\DeclareOption{jabr}{%
  \def\@jlogo{jabr-logo}%
  \def\@jname{J Appl Behav Res}%
  \def\@jwebsite{wileyonlinelibrary.com/journal/jabr}%
}

%% Options for bibliography style
\DeclareOption{num-refs}{
  \@numrefstrue
  \@alpharefsfalse
  \@amsrefsfalse
}
\DeclareOption{alpha-refs}{
  \@numrefsfalse
  \@alpharefstrue
  \@amsrefsfalse
}
\DeclareOption{ams-refs}{
  \@numrefsfalse
  \@alpharefsfalse
  \@amsrefstrue
}

%% Option for blind review
\DeclareOption{blind}{\@blindreviewtrue}

\ExecuteOptions{num-refs}
\ProcessOptions\relax


\LoadClass[twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{textcase}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{authblk}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{soul}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}


\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\ifxetexorluatex
  \RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\else
  \ifpdf
    \RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
  \else
    \RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{microtype}{tracking amount list}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Reference `mdf@pagelabel}

\ifxetexorluatex
  \RequirePackage{microtype}
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
  \RequirePackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
  \setmathfont[range={\int}]{Latin Modern Math}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{Lato Italic}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{Lato Bold}
\else
  \RequirePackage{microtype}
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \RequirePackage[default]{lato}
  \IfFileExists{newtxsf.sty}{
    \RequirePackage[cmintegrals,nosymbolsc]{newtxsf}
  }{}
  \ifpdf
  \SetTracking[spacing={500*,166,}]{encoding={*}}{80}
  \fi
\fi


\RequirePackage
 [paperwidth=171mm,paperheight=246mm,
  left=14.3mm,textwidth=142.4mm,lines=47,
  headsep=\baselineskip,headheight=16\p@,
  footskip=23\p@]
{geometry}

\RequirePackage{alphalph}
\newalphalph{\fnsymbolmult}[mult]{\@fnsymbol}{5}

\newcounter{authorfn}
\setcounter{authorfn}{1}
\newcommand{\authfn}[1]{%
  \fnsymbolmult{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\presentadd}[2][]{
  \ifx\empty\@presentaddress\else\appto{\@presentaddress}{\\}{}{}\fi
  \appto{\@presentaddress}{%
  \ifx\empty#1\else\textsuperscript{#1}\fi
  #2%
  }{}{}
}


%% These will be set by the \journal{} command
\newcommand{\jlogo}[1]{\def\@jlogo{#1}}
\newcommand{\jname}[1]{\def\@jname{#1}}
\newcommand{\jyear}[1]{\def\@jyear{#1}}
\newcommand{\jvolume}[1]{\def\@jvolume{#1}}
\newcommand{\jpages}[1]{\def\@jpages{#1}}
\newcommand{\jwebsite}[1]{\def\@jwebsite{#1}}


\newcommand{\runningauthor}[1]{\def\@runningauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\corraddress}[1]{\def\@corraddress{#1}}
\newcommand{\corremail}[1]{\def\@corremail{#1}}

\newcommand{\fundinginfo}[1]{\def\@fundinginfo{#1}}

\newcommand{\paperdoi}[1]{\def\@paperdoi{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperreceived}[1]{\def\@paperreceived{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperrevised}[1]{\def\@paperrevised{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperaccepted}[1]{\def\@paperaccepted{#1}}
\newcommand{\papereditor}[1]{\def\@papereditor{#1}}
\newcommand{\papertype}[1]{\def\@papertype{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperfield}[1]{\def\@paperfield{#1}}

% normal font is 8pt/13pt
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[13\p@]{8\p@}

% sectional headings
\ifxetexorluatex
  \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][10.0]{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=#1}\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}
  %% Fake small caps
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0,Scale=0.8}\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
\else
  \ifpdf
    \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][]{\textls*[#1]{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}}
  \else
    \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][]{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad\allcaps{#1}}

\newcommand{\backmatter}{%
  \titleformat{\section}
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
    {}{0pt}{\allcaps{##1}}%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{ 1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
}

\ifxetexorluatex
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
    {}{0pt}{\textsc{#1}}
\else
  \ifpdf
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\scshape\bfseries}
    {}{0pt}{\textls*{#1}}
  \else
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\scshape\bfseries}
    {}{0pt}{#1}
  \fi
\fi
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{name=\section,numberless}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad#1}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\ifxetexorluatex
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
    {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontspec{Lato Black}\color{black!75}}
    {\theparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
  \titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[hang]
    {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontspec{Lato Black}}
    {}{0pt}{#1}
\else
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
    {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\color{black!75}}
    {\theparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
  \titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[hang]
    {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
    {}{0pt}{#1}
\fi
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}

\ifxetex
  \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
    {\normalsize\fontspec{Lato Black}\color{black!75}}
    {\thesubparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
\else
  \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
    {\normalsize\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\color{black!75}}
    {\thesubparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
\fi
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{1em}


% Formatting of footer for first page
\RequirePackage[flushmargin,bottom]{footmisc}
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\appto{\footnotelayout}{\fontsize{6\p@}{9\p@}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\noindent\textcolor{black!50}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5\p@}}\vskip2\p@}


%% Headers
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\fancyhead[LO]{{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X r | r @{}}%
  \textsc{\@runningauthor} & & \thepage\\\hline
  %& %\multicolumn{1}{r}{%
    %\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2.5em]{\@jlogo}}%
    %\quad%
    %\raisebox{0.25em}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[height=2em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}}}} & \\
\end{tabularx}%
}}

\fancyhead[LE]{{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l | l >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X @{}}%
  \thepage & & \textsc{\@runningauthor}\\\hline
%   \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{} &
%   \raisebox{0.25em}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[height=2em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}}}%
%   \quad%
%   \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2.5em]{\@jlogo}}\\
  \end{tabularx}%
}}

%% First page header + footer
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
%   \renewcommand{\footrule}{\hdashrule{\textwidth}{0.5\p@}{2\p@}\\[-2\p@]}

  \fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l | l | X @{}}%
  \ifdefempty{\@paperreceived}
    {\multicolumn{3}{l}{}}
    {Received: \@paperreceived &
  Revised: \@paperrevised &
  Accepted: \@paperaccepted}
  \\\hline
  \ifdefempty{\@paperdoi}{}{\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{DOI: \@paperdoi}}
  \end{tabularx}}

  \fancyfoot[L]{%\fontsize{7\p@}{10pt}\selectfont%
%   \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
%   \arrayrulecolor{black}\raggedright%
%   This is an open access article under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution License, which permits use, distribution and reproduction in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited.\\[3\p@]
%   \begingroup
  \fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X  >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  r | r @{}}%
  \hline
  \ifdefempty{\@paperreceived}{& & & }{%
  \textit{\@jname}~\@jyear; \@jvolume: \@jpages &
  \@jwebsite &
  \textcopyright~\@jyear\space Wiley Periodicals, Inc. &
  }
  \thepage
  \end{tabularx}%
%   \endgroup
  }
}

% For adding notes about author contributions
\newcommand{\contrib}[2][]{%
  \blfootnote{\textsuperscript{#1}#2}%
}


% Author and affiliation fonts
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{1}
\renewcommand{\Authsep}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authand}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authands}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\fontsize{12\p@}{20pt}\bfseries\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\fontsize{7\p@}{10pt}\selectfont\raggedright}
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\patchcmd{\AB@affilsepx}{\\}{\\[3\p@]}{}{}

\patchcmd{\@author}{\AB@authlist\\[\affilsep]\AB@affillist}{\AB@authlist}{}{}

% % \AtBeginDocument{
%   \if@blindreview
%     \let\oldauthor\author
%     \let\oldaffil\affil
%     \renewcommand{\author}[2][]{\oldauthor{Author}}
%     \renewcommand{\affil}[2][]{\oldaffil{An affiliation}}
% % %     \def\AB@authors{Anonymous Authors}
% %     \def\AB@affillist{Anonymous Affiliations}
%   \fi
% % }

% Title
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \if@blindreview
    \def\AB@authlist{\Authfont Anonymous Authors}
    \def\AB@affillist{\Affilfont Anonymous Affiliations}
    \def\@runningauthor{Authors (Anon)}
    \def\@corraddress{Anonymous correspoundence}
    \def\@corremail{anon@example.com}
    \def\@presentaddress{Anonymous present address}
    \def\@fundinginfo{Anonymous funders}
  \fi
  \vspace*{\dimexpr 27\p@-2\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\begingroup%
  \setul{3\p@}{1\p@}%
  \ifxetexorluatex\fontspec{Lato Heavy}\else\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\fi
  {\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\allcaps[\ifxetexorluatex 20\else 200\fi]{\ul{\@papertype}}}
  \ifdefempty{\@jlogo}{\rule{0pt}{2em}}{%
  \hfill%
%   \includegraphics[height=1.5em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}%
%   \quad%
  \includegraphics[height=2em]{\@jlogo}}
  \\[2\p@]%
  {\fontsize{8\p@}{15\p@}%
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\@paperfield%
  \else
    \ifpdf
    \textls*[150]{\@paperfield}%
    \else
    \@paperfield
    \fi
  \fi}
  \endgroup%
  \vskip13\p@%
  {\fontsize{18\p@}{23\p@}\bfseries\raggedright\@title\par}
  \vskip27\p@%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}\@author\end{minipage}%
  \vskip21\p@%
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}
}

% Affiliation + other metadata
\newcommand{\wiley@affilmetadata}{%
  \AB@affillist\par%
  \vskip10pt%
  \textbf{Correspondence}\\
  \@corraddress\\
  Email: \@corremail\par
  \ifx\empty\@presentaddress
  \else%
    \vskip10pt%
    \textbf{Present address}\\
    \@presentaddress\par
  \fi%
  \vskip10pt%
  \textbf{Funding information}\\
  \@fundinginfo\par
  \ifdefempty{\@papereditor}{}
  {\vskip10pt Editor: \@papereditor\par}
}

%% Abbreviations in the footnote
\newcommand{\abbrevs}[1]{\blfootnote{\textbf{Abbreviations:} #1\\[-3\p@]}}

%% Abstract and affiliation in the margin
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\reversemarginpar
\newlength{\wiley@affilmetadataheight}
\newlength{\wiley@abstractheight}
\NewEnviron{wiley@abstract}{%
  \newcommand{\keywords}[1]{%
    \vskip8\p@%
    \noindent{\bfseries\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\allcaps[\ifxetexorluatex 20\else 200\fi]{keywords}\par}
    \noindent{\raggedright\fontsize{8\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont ##1\par}
  }%
  \strictpagecheck%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{\dimexpr 54.9mm-6.5\p@}{}%
  \setlength{\marginparsep}{-47mm}%
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{47mm}%
  %% Measure the height of the affil metadata in the sidebar
  \settototalheight{\wiley@affilmetadataheight}{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\wiley@affilmetadata}}%
  \newsavebox{\wiley@abstractbox}%
  %% Save the abstract text in a box
  \savebox{\wiley@abstractbox}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[font=\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\selectfont,
      topline=false,bottomline=false,
      leftline=true,rightline=false,
      backgroundcolor=black!10,
      middlelinewidth=6\p@,middlelinecolor=white,
      outerlinewidth=0.5\p@]
      \BODY
    \end{mdframed}}%
  }%
  \settototalheight{\wiley@abstractheight}{\usebox{\wiley@abstractbox}}%
  \marginpar{\wiley@affilmetadata}\vskip-1.5em%
  \begin{mdframed}[font=\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\selectfont,
  topline=false,bottomline=false,
  leftline=true,rightline=false,
  backgroundcolor=black!10,
  middlelinewidth=6\p@,middlelinecolor=white,
  outerlinewidth=0.5\p@]%
  \BODY
  \end{mdframed}%
  %% If the affildata is taller than the abstract, add vskip
  \ifdimgreater
    {\wiley@affilmetadataheight}
    {\wiley@abstractheight}
    {\vskip\dimexpr\wiley@affilmetadataheight-\wiley@abstractheight+\baselineskip\relax}{}
}[\end{adjustwidth*}]%

\renewcommand{\abstract}{\wiley@abstract}
\renewcommand{\endabstract}{\endwiley@abstract}

% quotes and epigraphs
\RequirePackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=\baselineskip,indentfirst=false,font={itshape,RaggedRight,normalsize},leftmargin=26\p@,rightmargin=26\p@}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{quoting}}{\end{quoting}}

\renewenvironment{quotation}{\begin{quoting}}{\end{quoting}}

\newenvironment{epigraph}[1]
{\begin{quoting}\def\@quotesource{#1}}
{\par\hfill\@quotesource\end{quoting}}

\newenvironment{pullquote}
{\begin{quoting}[vskip=\dimexpr 39\p@-23\p@\relax,leftmargin=12\p@,rightmargin=12\p@,font+={raggedright},begintext={\fontsize{18\p@}{23\p@}\selectfont\color{black!50}}]}
{\end{quoting}}

% Enum/itemized
\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,font=\bfseries,leftmargin=*,align=left}
\setlist[1]{topsep=\baselineskip,leftmargin=\parindent,labelsep=*,labelwidth=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*.},}

% Space above/below equations
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{\baselineskip}%
}

% All the popular math environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][Example]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\newcommand{\qed}{\nobreak \ifvmode \relax \else
      \ifdim\lastskip<1.5em \hskip-\lastskip
      \hskip1.5em plus0em minus0.5em \fi \nobreak
      \vrule height0.75em width0.5em depth0.25em\fi}

% Captions
\RequirePackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{captionfont}{\fontsize{8\p@}{11\p@}\selectfont}
\DeclareCaptionFont{boxcaption}{\fontsize{9\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont}
\ifxetexorluatex
  \DeclareCaptionFont{heavy}{\fontspec{Lato Black}}
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15.0}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}}
\else
  \DeclareCaptionFont{heavy}{\fontseries{eb}}
  \ifpdf
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\textls[150]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}}
  \else
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}
  \fi
\fi
\captionsetup*{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=captionfont,labelformat=allcaps,labelfont={heavy},labelsep=quad}
\captionsetup*[table]{skip=0.5ex}

% Tables
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
  \fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont%
  \rowcolors*{3}{black!10}{}%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black!20}%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1\p@}%
}

\RequirePackage{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\leftmargin=0pt}
\newcommand{\headrow}{\rowcolor{black!20}}
\newcommand{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries #1\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{2em}}}

%% Boxes!
\RequirePackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement=bt,name=box]{featurebox}
\captionsetup*[featurebox]{skip=1em,labelformat={default},font={heavy,boxcaption},labelfont={sc,color=black!75}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{featurebox}{%
  \setlist*{topsep=0pt}%
}
\apptocmd{\featurebox}{%
  \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=5\p@,linecolor=black!20,
  innerleftmargin=12\p@,innerrightmargin=12\p@,
  innertopmargin=12\p@,innerbottommargin=12\p@]
}{}{}
\pretocmd{\endfeaturebox}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}


% Skips for floats
\setlength{\floatsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{1.5\baselineskip}

% The endnotes
\RequirePackage{enotez}
\newlist{enotezlist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[enotezlist,1]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*,labelsep=0.25em,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0.5\baselineskip}
\EditInstance{enotez-list}{itemize}
{list-type=enotezlist}
\setenotez{list-name={endnotes},list-style=itemize}
\EditInstance{enotez-list}{itemize}{
  format=\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont,
  number = \textsuperscript{#1}
}

% References
\if@numrefs
  \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{vancouver-authoryear}
\fi
\if@alpharefs
    \RequirePackage{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{rss}
\fi
\if@amsrefs
  \RequirePackage{amsrefs}
  \let\citep\cite
  \let\citet\ocite
  \renewcommand{\biblistfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont}
\fi

\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{natbib}{
    \setlength{\bibhang}{1.5em}
    \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand{\refname}{references}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{references}
  }{}

  \@ifpackageloaded{amsrefs}{
    \renewcommand{\biblistfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand{\refname}{references}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{references}
  }{}
}

% Author biography
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\newenvironment{biography}[2][]
{\begin{mdframed}
  [linewidth=0.5\p@,skipabove=1.5\baselineskip,%nobreak,
    innerleftmargin=6\p@,innerrightmargin=6\p@,
    innertopmargin=6\p@,innerbottommargin=6\p@]
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}
  {\lettrine[image,lines=5,findent=1em,nindent=0pt]{#1}{}}%
  {\bfseries\scshape #2}}
{\end{mdframed}}

\newcommand{\otherinfo}[2][]{%
  \backmatter%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{suppinfo}
  {\section{Supporting Information}
  Additional Supporting Information may be found online in the supporting information for this article.}
  {}

  \begin{mdframed}
  [linewidth=1\p@,linecolor=black!40,nobreak,
    innerleftmargin=12\p@,innerrightmargin=12\p@,
    innertopmargin=12\p@,innerbottommargin=12\p@,
    skipabove=\baselineskip]
  \textbf{How to cite this article:} #2
  \end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{graphicalabstract}[1]{%
  \backmatter
  \section{graphical abstract}
  \lettrine[image,lines=10,findent=1em,nindent=0pt]{#1}{}%
}{}

% Here we go!
\normalsize
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

And a MWE

```
\documentclass[alpha-refs]{wiley-article}


\title{This is my title}

% List abbreviations here, if any. Please note that it is preferred that abbreviations be defined at the first instance they appear in the text, rather than creating an abbreviations list.
\abbrevs{ABC, a black cat; DEF, doesn't ever fret; GHI, goes home immediately.}

% Include full author names and degrees, when required by the journal.
% Use the \authfn to add symbols for additional footnotes and present addresses, if any. Usually start with 1 for notes about author contributions; then continuing with 2 etc if any author has a different present address.
\author[1]{author 1}
\author[1]{author 2}

% \contrib[\authfn{1}]{Equally contributing authors.}

% Include full affiliation details for all authors
\affil[1]{same address}


\corraddress{author 1}
\corremail{author1@mail.com}

% \presentadd[\authfn{2}]{Department, Institution, City, State or Province, Postal Code, Country}

% \fundinginfo{}

% Include the name of the author that should appear in the running header
\runningauthor{Author One et al.}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is a generic template designed for use by multiple journals, which includes several options for customization. Please consult the author guidelines for the journal to which you are submitting in order to confirm that your manuscript will comply with the journal's requirements. Please replace this text with your abstract.

% Please include a maximum of seven keywords
\keywords{keyword 1, \emph{keyword 2}, keyword 3, keyword 4, keyword 5, keyword 6, keyword 7}
\end{abstract}

\section{First Level Heading}
Please lay out your article using the section headings and example objects below, and remember to delete all help text prior to submitting your article to the journal.

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

PS: I forgot to mention that I compile my document by using the `pdflatex` engine

Comment: First, why do you want to deactivate it?

Comment: Please don't make links pointing to external sites. Many users here don't have an Overleaf account, so they can't see Overleaf stuff. I do have an account, but I can't have access to your page.

Comment: since my research does not have any funding, i want to remove the "funding information" output

Comment: I see "Original Article". Do you want to remove it?

Comment: no, just the "funding information" part

Comment: After some slight modifies, I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOhKb.png), and I can't see the "Funding information".

Comment: can you provide these modifications as an answer?

Comment: I added answer, but that doesn't seem to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the "funding information" output you need to patch the used class.  You can do this with package `etoolbox` and command `\patchcmd` like this:

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\patchcmd{\wiley@affilmetadata}%
  {\textbf{Funding information}\\
   \@fundinginfo\par
  }%
  {\par}%
  {}% success
  {}%failure
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

Here I simply deleted the code for printing the bold text `Funding information` and the content of command `\fundinginfo{test}` I did **not** comment in the following complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[alpha-refs]{wiley-article}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================

\title{This is my title}

% List abbreviations here, if any. Please note that it is preferred that abbreviations be defined at the first instance they appear in the text, rather than creating an abbreviations list.
\abbrevs{ABC, a black cat; DEF, doesn't ever fret; GHI, goes home immediately.}

% Include full author names and degrees, when required by the journal.
% Use the \authfn to add symbols for additional footnotes and present addresses, if any. Usually start with 1 for notes about author contributions; then continuing with 2 etc if any author has a different present address.
\author[1]{author 1}
\author[1]{author 2}

% \contrib[\authfn{1}]{Equally contributing authors.}

% Include full affiliation details for all authors
\affil[1]{same address}


\corraddress{author 1}
\corremail{author1@mail.com}

% \presentadd[\authfn{2}]{Department, Institution, City, State or Province, Postal Code, Country}

\fundinginfo{Test} % <==================================================

% Include the name of the author that should appear in the running header
\runningauthor{Author One et al.}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\patchcmd{\wiley@affilmetadata}%
  {\textbf{Funding information}\\
   \@fundinginfo\par
  }%
  {\par}%
  {}% success
  {}%failure
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is a generic template designed for use by multiple journals, which includes several options for customization. Please consult the author guidelines for the journal to which you are submitting in order to confirm that your manuscript will comply with the journal's requirements. Please replace this text with your abstract.

% Please include a maximum of seven keywords
\keywords{keyword 1, \emph{keyword 2}, keyword 3, keyword 4, keyword 5, keyword 6, keyword 7}
\end{abstract}

\section{First Level Heading}
Please lay out your article using the section headings and example objects below, and remember to delete all help text prior to submitting your article to the journal.

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

It results in the following first pdf page:

[image: first pdf page]

without any funding information inside the red circle ...