# Empty .bbl file on a `wiley-article` document class

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using the `wiley-article` document class develped by `overleaf`. The `.cls` file can be found on my previous question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485500/remove-the-output-of-a-custom-command-fundinginfo-in-a-custom-class/485511#485511).

The problem I face is that even though the `.bbl` file is generated, it is actually empty.

Among others, the class loads the `natbib` package with the `rss` bibliography style. My guess is that the problem relates to the class specification, but I cannot find how to solve the problem.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[alpha-refs]{wiley-article}


\title{This is my title}

% List abbreviations here, if any. Please note that it is preferred that abbreviations be defined at the first instance they appear in the text, rather than creating an abbreviations list.
\abbrevs{ABC, a black cat; DEF, doesn't ever fret; GHI, goes home immediately.}

% Include full author names and degrees, when required by the journal.
% Use the \authfn to add symbols for additional footnotes and present addresses, if any. Usually start with 1 for notes about author contributions; then continuing with 2 etc if any author has a different present address.
\author[1]{author 1}
\author[1]{author 2}

% \contrib[\authfn{1}]{Equally contributing authors.}

% Include full affiliation details for all authors
\affil[1]{same address}


\corraddress{author 1}
\corremail{author1@mail.com}

% \presentadd[\authfn{2}]{Department, Institution, City, State or Province, Postal Code, Country}

% \fundinginfo{}

% Include the name of the author that should appear in the running header
\runningauthor{Author One et al.}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is a generic template designed for use by multiple journals, which includes several options for customization. Please consult the author guidelines for the journal to which you are submitting in order to confirm that your manuscript will comply with the journal's requirements. Please replace this text with your abstract.

% Please include a maximum of seven keywords
\keywords{keyword 1, \emph{keyword 2}, keyword 3, keyword 4, keyword 5, keyword 6, keyword 7}
\end{abstract}

\section{First Level Heading}
Please lay out your article using the section headings and example objects below, and remember to delete all help text prior to submitting your article to the journal \citep{barkema1995top}

\bibliography{test}
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

where the `test.bib` file is located in the same folder as my `.tex` file. Also, the class loaded by default the `rss` bibliographic style once the `alpha-refs` option is used in `documentclass`. The `rss.bst` file is also located in that folder.

Finally, here is BMWE

```
@Article{barkema1995top,
  Title                    = {Do top managers work harder when they are monitored?},
  Author                   = {Barkema, Harry G and others},
  Journal                  = {KYKLOS-BERNE-},
  Year                     = {1995},
  Pages                    = {19--19},
  Volume                   = {48},

  Publisher                = {Wiley Online Library}
}
```

Finally, the `rss.bst` file can be found [here](https://www.stat.wisc.edu/~larget/cpma522/rss.bst)

Comment: Please show us a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) .

Comment: presumably overleaf can show you the latex and bibtex log files, what errors do you get?

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you show the .blg file?